# Keycloak with Angular + TypeScript for iOS/Android

Tags: authentication, angular2-nativescript, keycloak

I have an Angular(2) + TypeScript application using Keycloak as the authentication/authorization provider,
would like to integrate Keycloak with NativeScript to make the existing web application cater to iOS/Android users.

could see Keycloak supports iOS/Android as listed here : http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/securing_apps_guide/topics/overview/supported-platforms.html?408DD571-0042-4EBB-BC37-1F2966A56651=123451

Is there any NativeScript based plugin to integrate with Keycloak (could not find anything here : http://plugins.nativescript.org/ ) ? pointers for a possible solution would be of great help

Version:
tns --version
2.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is no. But I start playing around, and to create a plugin, we have basically two strategies:

1. Extend a pure OAuth client for nativescript. There is this plugin: http://plugins.nativescript.org/plugin/nativescript-oauth
2. Port the keycloak.js to Nativescript.

I like the second approach because there are more features build in keycloak, so my first try was edit the original code and remove the use of window and other API's that are not present in the browser. I quickly find out that keycloak.js code is a mess (at least to me), and I'm getting a bad time undestanding how to edit its 1258 lines. Because of that, I start a complete rewrite, highly inspired in the original. I'm actualy reading the code and trying to port the project piece by piece, reorganizing for test, and abstracting the use of browser API's to port for web and nativescript.
You can check the code here: https://github.com/atende/keycloak-js-universal but is not close to ready.

The problem is, I have no time to do it :-), but will get done eventually, because I need that too.

Is important to mention that I create a abstraction for Angular 2 that works using the keycloak.js for security, and porting the keycloak.js is strategic to make the library work for Angular 2 Nativescript, which is on my motivation to do it. You can check the project here: https://github.com/atende/angular-spa

Any contributions are wellcome ;-)